# What technologies should I look at for linking an iOS client app to a asp.net backend for secure communications?

Tags: c#, ios, api, security, authentication

I have a web app in my company that does a variety of things, it is coded in C# ASP.Net and it works very well for what it is intended.

At this point in time, it only works from within the company LAN (or on VPN) it has basic (AD based) SSL and uses username/passwords stored in a database.

Someone had the idea of making an iOS (and possibly android later) front end for it. I only briefly touched iOS developing in the past and am trying to pick it up again now.

I've just done version 1 which is really a cheat...  Having a whole page web frame that simply loads a new HTML5 responsive version of the app.

I really want to get a proper rich client version going, but, I am having problems getting off the starting line - I can build a basic API, but, I don't know what technologies to look at to make it secure.

Ideally I need something that works as a client on iOS, and server using ASP.Net c# - but, I am willing to learn/use other technologies.

I have been struggling for the past week trying to find courses or what direction to go down, but, I'm just hitting brick walls and haven't made much progress. Can anyone give me a kick in the right direction?

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow; you're asking for technology recommendations. Plus it's broad, and opinion-based. There's simply no right answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon That's what I thought :( I've just been going round in circles and not making much progress for the last week. I couldn't see an active Ios chat room here and I just need someone to give me a kick in the right direction :( I thought it may be closed, but, at least there is one good answer already.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use a REST framework for your server, something like WebApi5 or servicestack, it's likle a webservice but in other flavor, more lightweight and really the most used today.

For the client part, I would suggest use Xamarin, if you use Xamarin you can create a Xamarin Forms app and kill two birds with a shot, get iOS and Android, then, in the clients use something like RestSharp, this will lead you to use technologies what you already know (C#, XAML, etc) with really good results.

I work exactly doing things like that, I have created my own REST system through the years, but to start I would recomend using WebApi as it would maintain your infrastructure.

Comment: I've used rest sharp on a previous project and I like it! I will most likely be using that for big chunks of the project, but, I have a bigger concern at the moment with how do I authenticate and how do I actually make sure that the rest sharp queries get run as the correct user - I'm struggling to work out authentication with webapi and then how to utilise it on the ios app.

Comment: Want an advice? just forget aabout the standard mechanism and use your owns. When you start a session, the server will store it serialized to DB (I use DB because of clustering, we have 10 servers and each query is in round-robbin balancing) with a GUID as the primary key, send this GUID to the response of the start session, and when the client wants to execute a protected function it must include in the header this token as Authentication x-auth-token or whatever you whant, then, in the beginning of the protected resources just try to restore the session from db

Answer (score -1):

I work on [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) which as a primary goal aims to provide a productive development workflow for consuming .NET Web Services efficiently from both native iOS and Android Apps as well as C# iOS and Android Apps with Xamarin iOS/Android.

To enable this [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) provides an end-to-end Typed .NET Web Services API that can be consumed with native iOS Swift Apps with its [Swift Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swift-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) directly from within Xcode.

Using Xamarin for developing your mobile iOS and Android allows good re-use of your non-UI C# Business Logic which you can take advantage of in ServiceStack with its [.NET PCL Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) which lets you either share your DTO .dlls to enable an end-to-end typed API without code-gen.

Alternatively you can use [C# Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/CSharp-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) to instead generate and update the remote Web Service types directly in your VS.NET or Xamarin Studio projects.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against answering such shopping/decision-making questions in the future, as it'll only attract downvotes and spam flags. The community does not take kindly to promotional answers especially on off-topic questions.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep cool, only answered it as it was a new question that came under the search term 'servicestack' which I actively monitor where I'll instinctively just try to expand on the existing answer to provide more helpful context and links. Otherwise I'd never have answered.

Comment: Have a look at this library (https://github.com/kumait/HXF.net/wiki/HXF-Web-Services-Quick-Tutorial) that I have created, it allows you to create a light-weight web service and consume it from many clients (including iOS) easily. The proxy code for several clients is auto generated.